# SASS extend from root only

Tags: html, css, sass, extend, extending

I recently encountered a.. "thing" in the land of SASS. And maybe you guys know a trick or something alike to "fix" it.

I've got this class `.icon`. It contains some basic styling for my icons (Used for an iconfont). These icons can then be placed in the markup whereever I want. For example in a `button`. But inside the button this icon needs some extra styling. So I do the following:

```
.icon {
  // Basic styling
}

button {
  .icon {
    // Additional styling
  }
}
```

It compiles to this css:

```
.icon {
  // Basic styling
}

button .icon {
  // Additional styling
}
```

Everything OK so far. But now I want to extend the `.icon` to an after-element inside of all my `.foo` elements like so:

```
.foo:after {
  @extend .icon;
}
```

Now it compiles to this css:

```
.icon, .foo:after { // This is good, exactly what I want
  // Basic styling
}

button .icon, button .foo:after { // But I don't need the second half of this line
  // Basic Additional
}
```

Now the foo-element isn't just extending the "root" icon-class but also the icon-class under button and all its additional stylings. But I don't need that. I don't want that element to have that additional styling. It doesn't result in problems yet. But maybe that could happen later. So I was curious if it is possible to extend only the `.icon` from the root, omitting the nested `.icon` in the `button`, and possibly more nested icon-classes in other elements later on.

My first thought was to use an abstact class like `%icon` and extend from that, but the above mentioned icon-class, and the file that it is placed in, is generated by grunt-webfont. So I can't just change the icon-class styling 'cause its overwritten all the time.

What can I do? Is there some more to the extend function of SASS that I don't know of? Or is there a totally different way?

Thanks for any help.

SOLUTION:

Using all the awesome help and tips I found a way to avoid this problem:
Grunt-Webfont suggests to use the `i-tag` to display the icons. Font-Awesome does the same. So, I'm doing exactly that. And I usually don't use it for anything else.
This allows it to use the `i-tag` under the `button` for my extra styling, and not the `.icon` class. This way the `.icon` class is used only once in the generated file and then never again.

```
.icon {
  // Basic styling
}

button {
  i { // <= Previously '.icon'
    // Additional styling
  }
}
```

Comment: Question its not clear for me, but i think you want use parent selector: "&" (ampersand)

Comment: You don't have a choice here.  This is how `@extend` is supposed to work.  There is no magic "extend this class, but not if it is part of a more complex selector".

Comment: Can you user another class instead of the nested selector? Instead of `button .icon`, use `.button-icon` and add your additional styles there. Then add both your `.icon` and `.button-icon` class to your icon HTML inside of buttons.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried doing something like this?

```
.icon {
  //some styles from external (ie: grunt webfont)
  color: red;
}

%icon {
  @extend .icon;
}

button {
  .ico {
    @extend %icon;
    //add some additional styles
  }
}

.foo:after {
  @extend %icon;
  //add some more
}
```

You would then avoid generating the foo:after rule for the .icon inside the button.

*EDIT2* - you'll need to create an additional class which you can use inside your styles, so there's only one .icon class defined (in your grunt-webfont generated css). Then just use the .ico class inside your styles and extend the %icon placeholder like shown above.

*EDIT* - have you considered solving this problem in your grunt-webfont generator?
From the [documentation](https://github.com/sapegin/grunt-webfont), it seems you can set the output to scss like so:

```
options: {
      stylesheet: 'scss',
      mixinPrefix: 'mixin-'
```

Then just use the mixin to define the styles of your desired classes?

Comment: Again, the OP can't use this because the `button .icon` selector is generated dynamically.

Comment: I just gave that a try but it still resulted in the same css. Apparently the `%icon` isn't just extending the `.icon` in the root but also the `.icon` under `button`.

Comment: Oh, so your button { .icon {...} } is also defined in the grunt-webfont?

Comment: Oh. No no, sorry. I would be able to do as you suggested. Just the `.icon` class is generated and can't be modified. So I could put the other stuff in another file. But the code above doesn't change the resulting css. But I'll try your edit as soon as I can. Thanks :)

Comment: Ah yes, you are correct. If you add more styles behind the @extend placeholder you'll get the additional foo:after class aswell. If you don't want to add an additional "icon" class - it seems the simplest solution is to set the options in your grunt-webfont generator.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this gets the result you're looking for? Albeit, slightly messily.

The method: make a placeholder style and extend that into .icon to begin with.

```
%icon-styles{
  basic: styling;
}

.icon {
  @extend %icon-styles;
}

.foo:after {
  @extend %icon-styles;
}

button .icon {
  @extend %icon-styles;
  additional: styling;
}
```

It compiles into:

```
.icon, .foo:after, button .icon {
  basic: styling;
}

button .icon {
  additional: styling;
}
```

Comment: The OP already said that they can't do that because the file that contains the classes they want to extend is dynamically generated.

Comment: Yeahh, just realized I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use custom template with grunt-webfont. It’ll give you much more control on generated CSS.